# X11 programming font

Tags: x11

I'm new to X11 programming, and development is in Linux Environment, i have come across an issue with font which I'm not familiar.

**Here is my question:**

How to change the character set in `XmStringCreate(text,charset)` in `X11` ?

**For Example:**

`XmStringCreate(text,charset)` has the value `XmStringCreateLtoR(text,XmString_DEFAULT_CHARSET)`
I want to change the `DEFAULT_CHARSET` to `ISO859-15`.

And How to handle the `XmString_DEFAULT_CHARSET`.

Comment: Can you post a snippet of code?  That might help people give you a more specific answer.

Comment: In X11 - XmStrDefs.h we have,

#define XmSTRING_DEFAULT_CHARSET XmS
#define XmSTRING_ISO8859_1  "ISO8859-1"
...
...
...



now back to my code, i have

....
...
#define DLG_CHARSET XmSTRING_DEFAULT_CHARSET
....
...


function(... .. ..)
{
XmStringCreateLtoR(text, DLG_CHARSET);
...
string = XmStringCreateLtoR(value, XmSTRING_DEFAULT_CHARSET);

}

so everytime the text entered in a textbox widget take the default charset (XmSTRING_DEFAULT_CHARSET)) where i cannot enter any german characters. hence, i want to load other character set.

Would you help?

Comment: Please [edit] your question instead of adding code in comments.

Comment: By the way Motif is a really ancient, overcomplicated, broken in places, never properly supported toolkit. You are probably better off with almost anything else.

Comment: X11 font system is legacy, in large part because it couldn't handle international encodings efficiently. So just don't go there. The only encoding that sort of works with this generation of libs is iso-8859-1 (modernized as iso-8859-15). If you need to code a modern UI for UNIX systems, and want to use international encodings use a text stack based on fonctonfig and harfbuzz-ng

Answer (score 0):

The second argument to XmStringCreate is a string associated with a specific font via a fontlist resource, which any widget capable of displaying text has.

If you only need to display ISO8859-15, just put ISO8859-15 font(s) in your fontlist resource, and you're done.

If you need to display more that one legacy charset, put several fonts in your fontList and associate a *tag* with each one.

```
*fontList: -b&h-luxi sans-bold-o-normal--0-0-0-0-p-0-iso8859-1:charset1,
           -b&h-luxi sans-bold-o-normal--0-0-0-0-p-0-iso8859-15:charset2
```

Use `"charset1"` or `"charset2"` as the second argumnt to `XmStringCreate`.